# Opencart, disable shipping for some products

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I have OpenCart v.1.5.6.1 and I would like to disable the shipping step in checkout when the user buys some products. In the past there was a flag *requires shipping* in the *Data* tab of the product. Now I can't see it.

I've also made a research and still I can't find suggestions.
Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin that does just that. Is called "free shipping".
Probably the functionality was removed from the core.